# Create a dynamic quotation value in r

Tags: r

How can I create a value in r that is a quotation but comes from two other values
I'm using the package "lubridate" to get the end date.

```
start <- as.Date(2018-01-01)
end <- today()
```

I want to create a new value that's called "period" that is a quotation looking like:

"2018-01-01::2021-01-02"

I have tried using as.interval but it doesn't work.

I hope some of you are able to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with `paste0`.

First, you need to supply your date as a character string by using `"`.

`paste0()` concatenates strings together without any separators.

```
library(lubridate(
start <- as.Date("2018-01-01")
end <- today()
paste0(start,"::",end)
[1] "2018-01-01::2021-01-02"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!
I didn't know the paste0() function.
I made one small adjustment to the formula you provided to get rid of the backslash
paste0(start,"::",end)

Comment: @CasperIpsen ah, sorry, I was confused by an extra quotation mark in your question text. I edited the question and answer.